# How to access & modify the content of yaml file from python?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I would like to access and modify the content of a YAML file which looks like the following:

```
A: Sonstige
B:
  C: Sonstige
  D: null
  E: 1
```

I know that in order to access & modify the value of `A` in the above YAML file, I would use  code like the following:

```
def set_state(state):
    with open('my_file.yaml') as f:
        doc = yaml.load(f)

    doc['A'] = state

    with open('my_file.yaml', 'w') as f:
        yaml.dump(doc, f)
```

But what if I would like to modify the value of `E` in the above YAML file? How can I access the value of `E` and modify its value and dump it in a YAML file, similar to the above code. I have gone over the reference docs and was unable to find an answer for this.

Comment: Nested dictionary-usage? ```doc['B']['C']```? Not sure how pyyaml works, but just print out what ```doc['B']``` gives you, if it's a dict, well, easy.

Comment: doc['B']['C'] .. It works!.. It works.. Thanks a lot.. Wonder how I missed this!

Comment: Never ever use PyYAML `yaml.load()`, it is not necessary and unsafe.

Comment: @Anthon What is the alternate safe one that you'd recommend please?

Comment: It is called: `safe_load` so change to `yaml.safe_load()`. There is also a `safe_dump()` that will not try and dump any-and-all Python objects without complaint, but that is good enough you just work with dict/list and primitives (bool, string, int, float, datetime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the value for `E`, e.g. to `2` you could do the following:

```
import yaml

def set_state(state):
    with open('my_file.yaml') as f:
        doc = yaml.load(f)

    doc['B']['E'] = state

    with open('my_file.yaml', 'w') as f:
        yaml.dump(doc, f)

set_state(2)
```

To get to the value of `E` first index on `B`.

There are multiple problems with this in my experience:

1. You are using `load()` which in PyYAML is an unsafe operation without warning. Your data can be loaded with `safe_load()` and even if it couldn't it is much better to extend `safe_load()` to handle tags (and only those tags) than to extend `load()`.
2. Your output looks like:

   ```
   A: Sonstige
   B: {C: Sonstige, D: null, E: 2}
   ```

   not at all like your input, so use the option `default_flow_style=False` 
   to get something with your original block-style layout.
3. You don't need `dump()`, as data consisting of `dict`s, and primitives (and lists) can be dumped with `safe_dump()`. There is no safety issue there, but if you would call `set_state()` accidentally with a non-primitive:

   ```
   class Dice:
       def __init__(self, sides):
           self.sides = sides

   set_state(Dice(6))
   ```

   then `dump()` will silently generate the non-portable:

   ```
   A: Sonstige
   B:
     C: Sonstige
     D: null
     E: !!python/object:__main__.Dice {sides: 6}
   ```

   instead of raising an `Representer` error.
4. Any comments in your original file will be lost. PyYAML does not preserve these.

With PyYAML you should do:

```
import yaml

def set_state(state):
    with open('my_file.yaml') as f:
        doc = yaml.safe_load(f)

    doc['B']['E'] = state

    with open('my_file.yaml', 'w') as f:
        yaml.safe_dump(doc, f, default_flow_style=False)

set_state(2)
```

If you also want to preserve comments, or have a mixture of block-style and flow-style you want to preserve, I recommend you use `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author of that package):

```
import pathlib
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

def set_state(state):
    yaml = YAML()
    mf = pathlib.Path('my_file.yaml')
    doc = yaml.load(mf)

    doc['B']['E'] = state

    yaml.dump(doc, mf)
```

This has the same result as before, with the `load()` method being safe by default, preserving your layout (plus any comments in the YAML file you might have) and opening the `Path` instance for reading or writing as necessary (so you don't need the `with` statement, nor need the double action of calling `dump` and provide the `w` to `open()`).